# How do I replace same character occurrence with different characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like:

```
my_str = "select * from users where id = ? and name = ?;"
```

I also have an array to replace '?'

```
var arr = [1,'test']
```

I wanted to replace first ? with 1 and second ? with 'test' in 
jQuery/JavaScript dynamically. There can be a number of ? in string.

Note this question has no relation with MySQL the query I have written is just a string.

Comment: _no relation with MySQL_ then better change the string

Comment: if `?` occured 4 times means? as you said `?` number of string

Comment: is query always same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a more dynamic option, where `replace` is an array containing the replacements in order:

```js
const string = 'select * from users where id = ? and name = ?;'
const replace = [1, 'test']

let index = 0
const output = string.replace(/\?/g, () => replace[index++])
console.log(output)
```

Comment: this is the most suitable way for the question.

Comment: perfect answer!

Comment: Is it possible to get output like:


select * from users where id = 1 and name = 'test';

I need test in quotes because it's string.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma just put quotes inside the string, like so: `[1, "'test'"]`

Answer (score 2):

use replace method multiple times for replacing.

```js
var my_str = "select * from users where id = ? and name = ?;"

my_str = my_str.replace("?","1"); //replaces first "?"

my_str = my_str.replace("?","test"); //replaces second "?"

alert(my_str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `replace` function you can do that, just use `replace` multiple times to replace both '?'.

```js
var my_str = "select * from users where id = ? and name = ?;"
var arr = [1,'test']
my_str = my_str.replace("?",arr[0]).replace("?",arr[1]);
console.log(my_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `replace()` multiple times

```js
var r = "select * from users where id = ? and name = ?;".replace("?", '1').replace('?','test');
console.log(r);
```

and if you have an array of values to replace the '?':

```js
var arr = [1,'test']
var r = "select * from users where id = ? and name = ?;"
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  r = r.replace('?',arr[i]);
}
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get index of `?` and put into a array, then write a function to replace.

```js
    var str = "select * from users where id = ? and name = ?;"
    var indices = [];
    for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
        if (str[i] === "?") indices.push(i);
    }
    str = replaceAt(str,0,"1");
    str = replaceAt(str,1,"Jonh");
    alert(str);
    
    function replaceAt(str, index, replacement) {
     return str.substr(0, indices[index]) + replacement+ str.substr(indices[index] + 1, str.length);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vuph31/hgbms2s1/1/